# SQL PHP query multiple tables data

Tags: php, sql

Noob alert here!
I'm trying to display some data on my php page from two tables but I don't know how to do it

```
db_bandas TABLE  
banda_id | banda_name
    1    |  Rolling Beatles
    2    |  Linkin Bizkit



db_albuns TABLE  
album_id | album_name | banda_id | album_ano
    1    |    Music   |    1     |  2000
    2    |   another  |    2     |  2014
    3    |  good one  |    1     |  2004
```

What I want to show on the page is like :

```
 1  | Music    | Rolling Beatles | 2000 
 2  | another  | Linkin Bizkit   | 2014 
 3  | good one | Rolling Beatles | 2004
```

I've tried the query like this

```
$sql = "SELECT db_albuns.album_nome AS album_nome, db_albuns.album_id AS album_id, db_albuns.album_ano AS album.ano, db_banda.banda_nome AS banda_nome FROM db_albuns,db_banda";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few different ways you can do this, but my go-to is a LEFT JOIN.

```
$sql = "SELECT album_id, album_name, banda_name, album_ano
        FROM albuns LEFT JOIN bandas
        USING (banda_id)
        WHERE 1=1;
```

On a side not, prefixing your tables with db_ is a little confusing, because that's the name of a table, not a database.

Comment: Perfect! many many many thanks!!!

I know that I should not prefix with db....  thanks for warning!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Join to do it

```
$sql = "SELECT db_albuns.album_nome, 
db_albuns.album_id, db_albuns.album_ano, 
db_banda.banda_nome
FROM db_albuns join db_banda 
on  db_albuns.banda_id = db_banda.banda_id";
```

Comment: I didn't saw your tables structure. sorry i edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

Your table name should be **albums** and columns name should be **id, name, banda_id, ano**. Your table name is albums, so I think there is no need to use prefix 'albums' for each column.

As well as another table name should be **bandas** and columns name should be **id, name**

And your query should be like this

```
$sql = "SELECT albums.id, albums.name, bandas.name, albums.ano
        FROM albums JOIN bandas
        on albums.banda_id = bandas.id";
```